# Resizing list from a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I came across a problem when trying to do the resize as follow:

I am having a 2D array after processing data and now I want to resize the data, with each row ignoring the first 5 items.

What I am doing right now is to:

**edit: this apporach works fine as long as you make sure you are working with a list, but not string. it failed to work on my side because I haven't done the convertion from string to list properly.
so it ends up eliminating the first five characters in the entire string.**

```
2dArray=[[array1],[array2]]
new_Resize_2dArray= [array[5:] for array in 2dArray]
```

However, it does not seems to work as it just recopy all the element over to the `new_Resize_2dArray`.

I would like to ask for help to see what did I do wrong or if there is any scientific calculation library I could use to acheive this.

Comment: The code in your question is incomplete — please provide a runnable [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, because python list indexing is zero-based, your code should read `new_Resize_2dArray= [array[5:] for array in 2dArray]` if you want to not include the first 5 columns. Otherwise, I see no issue with your single line of code.

As for scientific computing libraries, `numpy` is a highly prevalent 3rd party package with a high-performance multidimensional array type `ndarray`. Using `ndarray`s, your code could be shortened to `new_Resize_2dArray = 2dArray[:,5:]`

Aside: It would help to include a bit more of your code or a minimum example where you are getting the unexpected result (e.g., use a fake/stand-in 2d array to see if it works as expected or still fails.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I realize it is my own problem that I think I am am working on the array but actually I haven't convert the string input into array properly. So I keeping working with deleting the first five elements in the string.

Comment: I will have my question edited. Thanks again.